# ionic 3 native storage clear when app close on ios

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, storage, hybrid-mobile-app

I m using native storage in ionic 3 but when I close the app it clear data automatically but works fine in android

```
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
constructor(private storage: NativeStorage, private http: HttpProvider) {
 this.storage.setItem('List', List);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue I changed to **@ionic/storage** and I fix it.

Comment: I already resolved issue with what you explained but this will not tell the answer with native storage problem